# What is the preferred method for storing application settings in Windows Mobile Applications?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am using the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and I am trying to determine if there is a standard way to store settings that a user to change in my application. I am aware of the Compact 3.5 SQL database, but I am trying to avoid that if I can to avoid a dependency that is not already installed on the user’s mobile device (I already have to worry about the 3.5 .NET Framework so I am trying to avoid any other dependencies if I can).

I saw that the old .config file (via System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings) is obsolete and doesn’t appear to be supported on the Compact framework anyway.

Aside from stuffing it in an xml file stored in /Application Data/My App/ and parsing it, are there any built in libraries for this type of functionality?

I am not seeing much online or on this site about this. Mostly non-compact framework solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer. This allowed us to store and restore settings with little effort. It is tolerant of changes to the settings when doing an upgrade/downgrade.

Comment: As I mentioned XMLSerializer is better than OpenNETCF.AppSettings

Answer (score 2):

[OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/ce88a94d-3a7e-b0dd-a363-d8d9d11fd447.htm) has support for loading and saving settings to an xml file

OpenNetCF.AppSettings namespace, and the SettingsFile class should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

I use the registry for many settings in my application.  We created a wrapper around registry calls that handle exceptions, memory cleanup, etc.  After that, it works pretty well.  I guess that all depends on what kind of settings you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

After testing OpenNetCF.AppSettings and trying to create a configuration manager from scratch, I ended up using [this class](http://blogs.freshlogicstudios.com/Posts/View.aspx?Id=2a18bfe7-caec-467d-913c-597627e92247). It's simple, and it just work.

**Edit:** the link above is dead, so I put the class source code [here](http://pastebin.com/qVeycKER).

Usage:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourSetting"]
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourSetting"] = "test";
```

Comment: I just had the same issue. The AppSettings object is disposed automatically after and I must recreate it each time I need to access it. It's a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Another fallback option is good old fashioned .INI files.  There's a number of pure C# classes out there for parsing them and using the values.  Simple and straightforward.