# store data in Windows mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am a windows phone developer. Now I am developing an application for windows mobile 6.5 that I was developed for windows phone before.

In my application I want to store some user credentials and some application settings. In windows phone I stored it in IsolatedStorageSettings. But how can I store them in windows mobile. ?

What is using in windows mobile similar to IsolatedStorageSettings ?. I want to keep this user entering settings in the phone until the application will uninstall.

Comment: You could save your data to the registry. Most device operators are not going to download some registry viewer, and devices (at least WM 6.5 and earlier) do not come with a Registry Editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsolatedStorageSettings are not supported with compact framework (3.5) on Windows Mobile (Embedded Handheld) 6.x.

As alternatives you may use an xml file or the registry or an ini file.

See also [What is the preferred method for storing application settings in Windows Mobile Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232472/what-is-the-preferred-method-for-storing-application-settings-in-windows-mobile). I would prefer using an xml or OpenNetCF AppSettings.

Here is another AppSettings implementation as xml: http://developers.de/blogs/andreas_lehmann/archive/2009/05/26/a-simple-implementation-of-config-files-for-windows-mobile.aspx